# cannot sending email in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I have some problem with sending invitation emails with My laravel app. this is My email form

```
@extends('layouts.app')

<!-- Main Content -->
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Send E-Mail Invitation</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/collaborators/invitationemail') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-envelope"></i> Send Invitation Link
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

EmailsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class EmailsController extends Controller
{
    public function send(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->get('email');


    Mail::send('emails.send', ['email' => $email], function ($message) use ($email)
    {
        $message->from('anyone.max@gmail.com', 'Andrew');

         $message->to($email);
    });

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Invitation Email Sent!']);
}
    //
}
```

routes

```
Route::get('projects/{projects}/collaborators/invitationemail','EmailsController@send');
```

when I going to send emal link it is generated following error

```
Swift_RfcComplianceException in MailboxHeader.php line 347:
 Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.
```

but amaizing when I change EmailsController as this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class EmailsController extends Controller
{
    public function send(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->get('email');


    Mail::send('emails.send', ['email' => $email], function ($message) use ($email)
    {
        $message->from('amal.fernandomax@gmail.com', 'Acxian');

         $message->to('somaakka@gmail.com');
    });

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Invitation Email Sent!']);
}
    //
}
```

email send without opening My email sending form....... I need open email sending form and send to different emails address can you help me

Comment: Try changing ```$request->get('email')``` to ```$request->input('email')```

Comment: same error here

Comment: What's your output for $request->all();?

Comment: generate following error **htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\Users\Max\Desktop\c\resources\views\emails\send.blade.php)**

Comment: Your email template is causing the error. Please show the code for emails.send.blade.php

Comment: **<html>
  <head></head>
  <body style="background: black; color: white">
    <h1>Email Invitation</h1>
    <p>Hello - {{$email}}</p>
    <p>....</p>
  </body>
</html>**